# How can i zoom in and out in a UIImageView without UIScrollView?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, ios-4.2, zooming

I'm developing an app for iOS 4.2, iPhone, in this app I download images and I save them in the internal storage (NSDocuments).

Well, then I show the first image in a UIImageView. The user can drag their finger on the UIImageView (TouchesMoved), when the user do that, I load other image. If the user drag down, I load one image, if drag up, i load other, and also with right and left.

This is all done. But I want to implement zooming. This is my code until now:

initialDistance --> is the distance between the fingers at first touch
finalDistance --> is the distance between the fingers each time they move
x --> is 0
y --> is 0

```
    // this method calculate the distance between 2 fingers
    - (CGFloat)distanceBetweenTwoPoints:(CGPoint)fromPoint toPoint:(CGPoint)toPoint {
        float xPoint = toPoint.x - fromPoint.x;
        float yPoint = toPoint.y - fromPoint.y;

        return sqrt(xPoint * xPoint + yPoint * yPoint);
     }

        //------------------- Movimientos con los dedos ------------------------------------
        #pragma mark -
        #pragma mark UIResponder

          // First Touch
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

switch ([allTouches count]) {
    case 1: { //Single touch

        //Get the first touch.
        UITouch *touch1 = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];

        switch ([touch1 tapCount])
        {
            case 1: //Single Tap.
            {
                // Guardo la primera localización del dedo cuando pulsa por primera vez
                //inicial = [touch1 locationInView:self.view];

            } break;
            case 2: {//Double tap. 
                //Track the initial distance between two fingers.
                //if ([[allTouches allObjects] count] >= 2) {

                // oculto/o no, la barra de arriba cuando se hace un dobleTap
                //[self switchToolBar];

            } break;
        }
    } break;
    case 2: { //Double Touch

        // calculo la distancia inicial que hay entre los dedos cuando empieza a tocar
        UITouch *touch1 = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
        UITouch *touch2 = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1];

        initialDistance = [self distanceBetweenTwoPoints:[touch1 locationInView:[self view]]
                                                 toPoint:[touch2 locationInView:[self view]]];
    }
    default:
        break;
}
}

// when the finger/s move to 
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

switch ([allTouches count])
{
    case 1: {



    } break;
    case 2: {
        //The image is being zoomed in or out.

        UITouch *touch1 = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
        UITouch *touch2 = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1];

        //Calculate the distance between the two fingers.
        CGFloat finalDistance = [self distanceBetweenTwoPoints:[touch1 locationInView:[self view]]
                                                       toPoint:[touch2 locationInView:[self view]]];

        NSLog(@"Distancia Inicial :: %.f, Ditancia final :: %.f", initialDistance, finalDistance);

        float factorX = 20.0;
        float factorY = 11.0;

        // guardo la posicion de los 2 dedos
        //CGPoint dedo1 = [[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0] locationInView:self.view];
        //CGPoint dedo2 = [[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1] locationInView:self.view];

        // comparo para saber si el usuario esta haciendo zoom in o zoom out
        if(initialDistance < finalDistance) {
            NSLog(@"Zoom In");

            float newWidth = imagen.frame.size.width + (initialDistance - finalDistance + factorX);
            float newHeight = imagen.frame.size.height + (initialDistance - finalDistance + factorY);

            if (newWidth <= 960 && newHeight <= 640) {
                /*
                 if (dedo1.x >= dedo2.x) {
                 x = (dedo1.x + finalDistance/2); 
                 y = (dedo1.y + finalDistance/2);
                 } else {
                 x = (dedo2.x + finalDistance/2); 
                 y = (dedo2.y + finalDistance/2);
                 }
                 */

                //x = (dedo1.x);
                //y = (dedo1.y);

                imagen.frame = CGRectMake( x, y, newWidth, newHeight);
            } else {
                imagen.frame = CGRectMake( x, y, 960, 640);
            }



        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Zoom Out");

            float newWidth = imagen.frame.size.width - (finalDistance - initialDistance + factorX);
            float newHeight = imagen.frame.size.height - (finalDistance - initialDistance + factorY);

            if (newWidth >= 480 && newHeight >= 320) { 
                /*
                 if (dedo1.x >= dedo2.x) {
                 x = (dedo1.x + finalDistance/2); 
                 y = (dedo1.y + finalDistance/2);
                 } else {
                 x = (dedo2.x + finalDistance/2); 
                 y = (dedo2.y + finalDistance/2);
                 }
                 */
                //x -= (finalDistance - initialDistance + factorX); 
                //y -= (finalDistance - initialDistance + factorX); 

                //x = (dedo1.x);
                //y = (dedo1.y);

                imagen.frame = CGRectMake( x, y, newWidth, newHeight);
            } else {
                imagen.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 480, 320);
            }



        }

        initialDistance = finalDistance;

    } break;
}
}

#pragma mark -
```

Thank you very much!!

PD: If there is a method with UIScrollView whitch I can move between different images, I m open to take a look too.

Comment: If you intend to use drag/pan events for moving to next image, how will the user navigate a zoomed image?

Comment: He only can zoom, not navigate.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok. You can consider using a UIScrollView if only to use it for its zoom functionality.

Say we have a `scrollView` and a `imageView` with both having the same bounds. Add the `imageView` as the subview of `scrollView`.

```
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size;
```

To support only zoom and not not panning in the `scrollView` your `viewController` will have to adopt the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol.

```
// Disabling panning/scrolling in the scrollView
scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

// For supporting zoom,
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;

...

// Implement a single scroll view delegate method
- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {
    return imageView;
}
```

By now we have zooming available. For swipes, you can use appropriately configured [UISwipeGestureRecognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Create a gesture for handling each swipe direction and add it to scroll view.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleRightSwipe:)];
rightSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
rightSwipe.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[scrollView addGesture:rightSwipe];
[rightSwipe release];
```

And retrieve the appropriate image based on the gesture and set it using `imageView.image = yourImage;`.

Comment: Ok, that works, but i want to use swipe like touchesMoved, because I need to change the Image when I m moving the finger. This works with 1 move, 1 image change.

Comment: Hmm.. I can suggest you to replace Swipe with Pan gesture recognizers. Configure the selector triggered by the pan gesture recognizer to behave like your touches moved method as it does contain the translation data for you to work with. But this would require each image view to be contained within a scrollView.

Comment: Alternately, you can look at the `transform` property in `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, with Deepak's help, I use the transform property of UIImageView to make the Zooming.

I use the CGFloat at the position [0,0] in the matrix of the CGAffineTransform to set the limits. I have to pass the CGFloat to a string at zoom in because when i compare it with 0 this is always true.

Finally this is my code in touchesMoved, if it's useful for someone:

```
// comparo para saber si el usuario esta haciendo zoom in o zoom out
        if(initialDistance < finalDistance) {
            NSLog(@"Zoom Out");

            CGAffineTransform transformer = CGAffineTransformScale(imagen.transform, 1.05, 1.05);

            NSLog(@"transformer :: A: %.f, B: %.f, C: %.f, D: %.f", imagen.transform.a, imagen.transform.b, imagen.transform.c, imagen.transform.d);

            if (transformer.a < 5) {
                [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
                [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.2];
                imagen.transform = transformer;
                [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
                [UIView commitAnimations];
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Zoom In");

            CGAffineTransform transformer = CGAffineTransformScale(imagen.transform, 0.95, 0.95);

            NSLog(@"transformer :: A: %.f, B: %.f, C: %.f, D: %.f", transformer.a, transformer.b, transformer.c, transformer.d);

            NSString *num = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", transformer.a];

            if (![num isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
                [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
                [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.2];
                imagen.transform = transformer;
                [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
                [UIView commitAnimations];
            }
        }
```

And of course, a lot of thanks to Deepak.