# how to make zoom in UIImageView work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, pinchzoom

i'm trying to get zoom to work on images i fetch from Flickr

i have a seperate xib which loads the image named 
***flickrImage.xib***
and here's it's controller

```
#import "flickerImageViewController.h"
#import <AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h>

#define ZOOM_VIEW_TAG 100
#define ZOOM_STEP 1.5

@interface flickerImageViewController ()
- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center;
@end

@implementation flickerImageViewController
@synthesize photoLargeInfo, flickrImage, scrollViewFlickr;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}
- (void)awakeFromNib{

}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //    flickrImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoLargeInfo]]];
    NSLog(@"photoLargeInfo %@",photoLargeInfo);

    //    flickrImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData     dataWithContentsOfURL:photoLargeInfo]];

    [flickrImage setTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];

// add gesture recognizers to the image view
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTwoFingerTap:)];

[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[twoFingerTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];

[self.scrollViewFlickr addSubview:flickrImage];
self.scrollViewFlickr.contentSize = CGSizeMake(flickrImage.frame.size.width, flickrImage.frame.size.height);
self.scrollViewFlickr.minimumZoomScale = .5;
self.scrollViewFlickr.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;
self.scrollViewFlickr.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.scrollViewFlickr.delegate = self;
self.scrollViewFlickr.zoomScale = 1.0;
self.scrollViewFlickr.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


[flickrImage addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[flickrImage addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
[flickrImage addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTap];

NSURL *entry = photoLargeInfo ;
[flickrImage setImageWithURL:entry placeholderImage:nil];

 //calculate minimum scale to perfectly fit image width, and begin at that scale
    float minimumScale = [self.scrollViewFlickr frame].size.width  / [flickrImage frame].size.width;
    [self.scrollViewFlickr setMinimumZoomScale:minimumScale];
    [self.scrollViewFlickr setZoomScale:minimumScale];

     }
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return YES;
}

//- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
//    return [flickrImage viewWithTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];
//}
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
    {
    return flickrImage;
    }
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
[self.scrollViewFlickr setZoomScale:scale+0.01 animated:NO];
[self.scrollViewFlickr setZoomScale:scale animated:NO];
}

#pragma mark TapDetectingImageViewDelegate methods

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
// single tap does nothing for now
}

- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
// double tap zooms in
float newScale = [self.scrollViewFlickr zoomScale] * ZOOM_STEP;
CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
[self.scrollViewFlickr zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
}

- (void)handleTwoFingerTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
// two-finger tap zooms out
float newScale = [self.scrollViewFlickr zoomScale] / ZOOM_STEP;
CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
[self.scrollViewFlickr zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark Utility methods

- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center {
CGRect zoomRect;

zoomRect.size.height = [flickrImage frame].size.height / scale;
zoomRect.size.width  = [flickrImage frame].size.width  / scale;

zoomRect.origin.x    = center.x - (zoomRect.size.width  / 2.0);
zoomRect.origin.y    = center.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0);

return zoomRect;
}

@end
```

i want to be able to zoom in my pictures. as of right now it does nothing. just showing the picture no scroll, no zoom
i even tried to follow this guide but that doesn't seem to work ? do i have a bug or something ?
[apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH102-SW2)

here's the h. file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface flickerImageViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{

}

//@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *photoLargeInfo;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *photoLargeInfo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *flickrImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollViewFlickr;
@end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048257/how-can-i-zoom-in-and-out-in-a-uiimageview-without-uiscrollview

Comment: What is in the .h file?

Comment: added the .h file yurish

Comment: Side note: to send notification to a person add @ sign before the person name. Back to the code: I don't see anything suspicious. Try to set contentSize to something large in `viewDidApper`, comment out the line where you set minimumZoomScale to the computed value and see if this changes something.

Comment: Not related notes: please format code identation for readability, remove commented out lines; try to shorten the test code, for example gesture recognizers unlikely the reason of the problem, remove them and if problem is still reproducible post updated code without them. Code in scrollViewDidEndZooming dosn't do anything useful, you can remove it. Also why do you add flickrImage as the scroll view subview programmatically? it should be already there after instantiation from the xib file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use QuickLook Framework please google some tutorials of it. I have personally utilized it in one of my project and it is good enough

Comment: tried that before. way to advanced or something. at least i can't implant it into my flickr gallery thingy

Answer (score 0):

try to implement

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)sourceScrollView
{
    CGFloat offsetX = (sourceScrollView.bounds.size.width > sourceScrollView.contentSize.width)?
    (sourceScrollView.bounds.size.width - sourceScrollView.contentSize.width) * 0.5 : 0.0;
    CGFloat offsetY = (sourceScrollView.bounds.size.height > sourceScrollView.contentSize.height)?
    (sourceScrollView.bounds.size.height - sourceScrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.5 : 0.0;
    self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(sourceScrollView.contentSize.width * 0.5 + offsetX,
                                           sourceScrollView.contentSize.height * 0.5 + offsetY);

}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{
    currentScale=scale;
}
```

and i zoom like that

```
-(void)zoom :(id) sender
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer=(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
    CGPoint pointLocation=[tapRecognizer locationInView:self.imageView];
    CGRect zoomRect=CGRectMake(pointLocation.x, pointLocation.y, 10, 10);
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=currentScale+0.5;
    [self.scrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=4;
}
```